# Pyplot - '3D' scatter plot - zlabel?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Minimum working example:

```
#Python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
z = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='g', s=20)
plt.xlabel("X data")
plt.ylabel("Y data")
#plt.zlabel("Z data") DOES NOT WORK
ax.view_init(60,35)
plt.show()
```

Question: how to set up the label of the Z axis? For some reason plt has the xlabel and ylabel properties, but not the zlabel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 3D plots the labels need to be changed using the axes objects.

Try something like this

```
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
```

Comment: I know this is nitpicking, but only the z-label NEEDs to be set like this. One can call plt.xlabel ("y")
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
That being said, thank you because I looked for labelling z :-).